# Is the antonym of "questioner" - "answerer"?

Tags: word-request

What is the opposite (antonym) of "**questioner**"?  I mean if the one who asks is called **questioner**, then it makes sense that the one who answers is called "**answerer**", but the issue that *Google chrome* marks it as a spelling mistake. In addition, [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=Answerer) doesn't show such word in it.

Nevertheless I found such words on Google and [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/answerer), but it caused me to think about it, maybe it is a new word or maybe it's not acceptable widely or it is a matter of American versus British English. So in what word I should to use if not in "answerer" for example in the following context:

> **Questioner**: How are you.
>
> **Answerer**(?): I am OK. Thank you.

Here is the picture of Google Chrome while marking this word as a spelling mistake:
[image]

Comment: There are plenty of valid words that Google marks as a spelling mistake. There’s also an entry in Collins dictionary https://www.thefreedictionary.com/answerer

Comment: Maybe it is a matter of Americam and British English? My Google Chrome is tuned to British English. Could it be a reason for that mark?

Comment: What makes you think that any spell checker has all variations of all of the valid words in English? Don't you find sometimes that some dictionaries have words that others don't?

Answer (score 1):

"Questioner" is itself an unusual word. A word for someone who responds to a questioner is 'respondent': Oxford Online Dictionaries:"A person who replies to something, especially one supplying information for a questionnaire or responding to an advertisement.". That word also has a technical meaning in the context of litigation.

Your best choice of word must depend very much on the context. It would be interesting to see a real life example in which "questioner" is the natural choice of word.